# Table-cell not working in IE, any idea?

Tags: html, css

An image is worth a thousand words, so here is one:

[image]

The upper image is the corect version, I used display:table-cell to avoid what happens in the second image in IE7. What do you suggest to use instead to avoid this case?

Here is the code used:

```
 <div class="sharerDataContainer">

    <img src="http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/perfectworld.png?w=145" width="90" alt="Andrew" />

    <div class="sharerData">

                <p class="sharerDataTitle">
                               <a href="http://example.org" target="_blank">
                                               Website Title Here
                               </a>
                </p>


                <p class="sharerDataAddress">
                               mbac.squarespace.com
                </p>


               <p class="sharerDataDescription">
                       Congratulations to Rachel Edwards, who won a fabulous Bloom Tea Treatment Box Set (worth £20) from our friends at Running Cupcake
               </p>

     </div>

  </div>
```

UPDATE:

CSS code:

```
.sharerDataContainer img {
    float: left;
}

.sharerData {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 0 solid #0077A5;
    color: #808080;
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 15px;
    padding: 0 10px !important;
    position: relative;
}

.sharerData .sharerDataDescription {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Are you asking why `display: table-cell` doesn't work in IE7? Are you asking how to make it look like the first screenshot in all browsers?

Comment: @Tsar added the CSS code

Comment: @thirtydot exactly, I'm asking how can I make it look like the first screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE7 [does not support `display: table-cell`](http://caniuse.com/css-table).

Though it's not really a problem in this instance, because there's no need for it. You can [replace it with `overflow: hidden`](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats) to achieve the same effect: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/AmNeV/

Comment: jsfiddle.net seems like a good resource :) I looked for something like that before...

Answer (score 1):

the simple cross-browser solution is to wrap the image in another `div`ision tag:

```
<div class="imgContainer">
  <img src="" width="90" alt="Andrew" />
</div>
```

and let it float:

```
.sharerDataContainer .imgContainer {
    float: left;
}
```

try it! http://jsfiddle.net/9U7e9/

Comment: @Tsar: Just for your info, this doesn't quite work as is. Check it in IE7: http://jsfiddle.net/9U7e9/1/ (I merely added some extra text)